# awk pattern is matching the wrong numbers

Tags: bash, shell, awk

My script does this

```
ls -1A | awk '/model[1-9]+.dat/' | while read FN
```

but when I increase model[1-9] to model[1-1000], it doesn't match the files I expect.

Comment: What do you want that `awk` program to do?

Comment: I have taken a guess at what you mean.  If I am right, you have shown us a lot of code that is not related to the actual problem.  Please try to make a smaller version of the script that shows the problem, and it will make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 2):

> when increase model[1-9] to model[1-1000] its taking random number
>
> likes model100.dat, model105.dat. model11.dat ...etc

No, it's not random.

`[1-1000]` doesn't mean "any number from 1 to 1000".  It means a number between 1 and 1, or 0, or 0, or 0.  Which is simply 0 or 1.  Which is obviously not what you meant.

If you want to look at only the first 1000 files, you can make a pattern that says the file name must have one digit `[0-9]`, two digits `[0-9][0-9]`, or three digits `[0-9][0-9][0-9]`.  Put `|` between each one to mean "or".  So it is written `([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9])`.  This means 0-999.

Then you can change your awk part to

```
awk '/^model([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9])\.dat$/'
```

Comment: ok thanks but awk '/^model([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9])\.dat$/'
does it's read file in serial pattern likes 1 ,2 ,3.....1000 files but not happens this when i run script. it sstarting 100, 101.........389, 38, 390 .......99,9...

Comment: #!/bin/bash
 cp raysum-params.ps raysum-params
 num1=1
#'/^v.*\.dat$/'
 ls -1A | awk '/^v([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9])\.dat$/' | while read FN
 do
./seis-spread "${FN}" sample.geom sample.ph sample.arr \
sample.tr P
./readtraces
 #cp data${num1}.ps
 if  [ "$num1" -lt 250 ]
 then
 echo "number: $num1 "FN =$FN ""
 fi
 mv fort.2 out${num1}.dat
 sed '1d' out${num1}.dat > data${num1}.dat
 rm out${num1}.dat
 let "num1= $num1+1"
 rm sample.arr sample.ph 
 done
 echo

Answer (score 2):

You don't need awk here at all, bash brace expansion should suffice.

```
for filename in model{1..1000}.dat; do ...; done
```